# Entity Framework populating wrong column with Foreign Key

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to stablish a one-to-one relationship but when I create data EF is setting the Foreign Key as the other column. Please see below my classes:

```
public class SWAChecklist
{

    public SWAChecklist()
    {
        this.Steps = new Steps() { SWAChecklist = this };
        this.Observers = new List<Observer>();
        this.PersonnelObserved = new List<PersonObserved>();
        this.JobFactors = new JobFactors() { SWAChecklist = this };
        this.Causes = new Causes() { SWAChecklist = this };
        this.Hazards = new Hazards() { SWAChecklist = this };
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }        
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Job { get; set; }
    public Causes Causes { get; set; }
}

public class Causes
{
    [Key]
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public int SWAChecklistId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual SWAChecklist SWAChecklist { get; set; }
    public bool? AdditionalHazard { get; set; }
    public bool? UnsafeBehavior{ get; set; }
    public bool? Planned { get; set; }
}
```

So when I try to create a SWAChecklist.Causes, it is assigning the id of the checklist to the column Id on Causes, instead of SWAChecklistId.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class SWAChecklist
{

    public SWAChecklist()
    {
        this.Steps = new Steps() { SWAChecklist = this };
        this.Observers = new List<Observer>();
        this.PersonnelObserved = new List<PersonObserved>();
        this.JobFactors = new JobFactors() { SWAChecklist = this };
        this.Causes = new Causes() { SWAChecklist = this };
        this.Hazards = new Hazards() { SWAChecklist = this };
    }
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }        
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Job { get; set; }
    public virtual Causes Causes { get; set; }
}

public class Causes
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("SWAChecklist")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]

    public bool? AdditionalHazard { get; set; }
    public bool? UnsafeBehavior{ get; set; }
    public bool? Planned { get; set; }
    public virtual SWAChecklist SWAChecklist { get; set; }
}
```

You can try it

Answer (score 2):

Lets suppose EF would allow you to establish a 1:0..1 relation with both, `ID` and `SWAChecklistId` on the dependent side. To avoid a 1:many relation, EF would need a UNIQUE constraint on the `SWAChecklistId`. Then you would have `SWAChecklistId`, a unique (foreign) key column - which is the perfect description for a primary key.

So, using a the same column as primary and foreign key is a good design decision for 1:0..1 relations and EF is following it.

If you (for any reason) need a separate foreign key, you can configure a 1:many relation and create a unique index on the foreign key to effectively restrict the "many" to 0..1